# Usar javascript dentro de PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito que al ingresar una contraseña en concreto, si es correcta que me redireccione a otra página.

¿Tengo que añadirle código javascript?

```
<?php
$password = "123456";
if ($_POST['password'] != $password) {
?>
<h2>Logueate</h2>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"></form>
<?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`header()`](http://php.net/header) para enviar una [cabecera HTTP `Location`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) que te redirija a una nueva URL, así que no es necesario usar JavaScript, pero puedes agregarlo tras enviar las cabeceras para asegurarte de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$password = "123456";
/* Compruebo si el formulario ha sido enviado con isset y el contenido */
if (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] == $password) {
    /* Redirigimos al usuario a la nueva página */
    header('Location: pagina_secreta.html');
    /* Finalizamos la ejecución para que no salga el formulario de nuevo */
    die('<script>window.location.assign("pagina_secreta.html")</script>');
}
?><h2>Logueate</h2>
<form name="form" method="post"
  action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">
    <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: gracias por los consejos